# java regex not working

Tags: java, regex

Why this regex isnt working for non-word and non-digits like this: )(ª º ?

```
sentence.split("[^(\\p{L}\\p{N})]");
```

Is it suposed to work or not?

PS: I can't find any information either on SOF or in the web

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you want to happen? Perhaps give example input with expected and observed output?

Comment: What's in the `sentence` variable, and what's your expected output?

Comment: i checked the words after the split, and there are words like this: "(wordA", "word(d", "wordº", "wordªª", and shouldnt. I think that expression will exclude this cases. In that case, how can i add "(", ")", "º", and "ª" to that regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better description of the problem would be nice, but I'm guessing you're looking for:

```
sentence.split("\\W+");
```

Comment: it workds. Thank you very much, i firstly used this pattern and was not working.